# Ruby 1.93 using library debugger and getting "unitiilized constant"

Tags: ruby, debugging

Ruby 1.93 Windows 8.1
Could someone show me an example of the following debugger command being entered on a command line. I am debugging using "require 'debug'" but have same problem starting from command line.  Basically just what you would type to show a constant contained in a class named 'Test'

v[ar] c[onst]      show constants of object

Have no problems with any other debugger commands but not sure I know what is expected for this command.  It tells me I need a Class/Module if i enter an object/instance. If I enter a class or module (both with constants) then I get

"uninitialized constant DEBUGGER__::Context::CONSTANT_VAL1 (NameError)"

=======================================================================
Here is complete code and results from debugger perhaps someone could 
try in their environment to see if results are the same.  Not sure where
I am going wrong as puts Test::CONST_VAL works fine with or without debug
(rdb:1) puts Test::CONST_VAL
Constant Value String
nil
(rdb:1)
Not sure if that second line with a nil is meaningful

=======================================================================

## ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22) [i386-mingw32] Windows 8.1

class Test
    CONST_VAL = "Constant Value String"
 end
obj = Test.new
puts Test::CONST_VAL        # "Constant Value String" prints OK
require 'debug'             # Same result at top of file
a = 1

Debug commands
v c Test::CONST_VAL Should be Class/Module: Test::CONST_VAL

v c Test                `block in debug_variable_info': uninitialized constant<br>

                    DEBUGGER__::Context::CONST_VAL (NameError)<br>
=begin full printout - path info removed after first line - include
 in event can provide some info
C:/Ruby/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/debug.rb:171:
in`block in debugvariable_info': uninitialized constant 
DEBUGGER__::Context::CONST_VAL (NameError)
1.9.1/debug.rb:150:in `eval'
1.9.1/debug.rb:150:in`block in var_list'
1.9.1/debug.rb:149:in `each'
1.9.1/debug.rb:149:in`var_list'
1.9.1/debug.rb:171:in `debug_variable_info'
1.9.1/debug.rb:478:in`block in debug_command'
1.9.1/debug.rb:240:in `catch'
1.9.1/debug.rb:240:in`debug_command'
1.9.1/debug.rb:691:in `trace_func'
1.9.1/debug.rb:905:in`block in '
from C:/Ruby/Notes/Control/Test2.rb:9:in `'
=end

Comment: Somewhat unrelated, but where you `obj = Test.new` that is unneeded because the constant you're referencing is already defined without the `Test` class being instantiated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want what's within the `Test` module's scope:

```
puts Test::CONSTANT_VAL_1
```

... to output the contents of the constant.

Hopefully I understood your question properly.

Comment: I had tried that earlier without success here is a little of the code

Comment: class Test_class
 CONSTANT_VAL1 = 55555
 include Methods
   def initialize(value)

Comment: class Test_class
 CONSTANT_VAL1 = 55555
 include Methods
   def initialize(value)
      .......

And debug result

(rdb:1) v c Test_class::CONSTANT_VAL1
Should be Class/Module: Test_class::CONSTANT_VAL1

Without debugger no problems accessing constants ie

"puts Test_class::CONSTANT_VAL1"

Works as expected with no debugger as does accessing constant in a module.

Comment: Sorry not sure how to get line breaks in code pasted in.

Short story your method works fine for both class and modules when debugger is not invoked.  But fails in debugger with 

(rdb:1) v c Test_class::CONSTANT_VAL1 Should be Class/Module:

Comment: The previous answer works but not for the question I thought I asked. Perhaps I did not make the question clear.  I need the correct equivalent format when used in the debug command below <br>
v[ar] c[onst] show constants of object<br>
As you can see from my code <br>